# asp.net core web app host on Linux Centos issues

Tags: linux, nginx, asp.net-core, centos7

I am new to Linux and read several articles to host asp.net core we applications on the Linux server. I have installed NGINX and modified /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. I ran this following command and it shows application started. I tried to check my application on the browser(using IP). It shows "502 Bad Gateway" error. I checked error log(/var/log/nginx/reverse_error.log) to see any errors. But it doesn't provide any relevant errors except http headers information. How to troubleshoot more on this issue?

```
$ sudo dotnet testapp.dll
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /var/www/testapp
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

### /etc/nginxsites-available/default

```
server { 
 listen 80; # [::]:80;
 listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse_access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse_error.log debug;
 #rewrite_log on;

 location / {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe following through this link helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1. There's a lot of points so it's hard to pinpoint what's wrong. I suspect something to do with headers

Comment: you must forward headers in startup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170709/nginx-and-certbot-wont-forward-to-443-only-port-5001-on-aspnet-core-and-kestre/55179084#55179084